# Database table union result

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm trying to show same table results in one column and it goes well using:

```
$sql = "(select * from ( select start as date from my_table union all select end from my_table ) tmp WHERE date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(),0) order by date limit 10)";
```

To imagine what I want to do:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the original data table, the one you are querying.

Comment: Sorry, made mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: I do not see the original table.  Is that the one up top.  If so I am lost, sorry.

Comment: Yes, this is the one up on top

Comment: Add table defintions

Comment: Why would you do that in `SQL`? Select the rows you need then split them in `PHP` any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way to achieve that result:

```
( SELECT s.start AS `date`
       , s.name  AS `name`
    FROM my_table s
   WHERE s.start > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY
   ORDER BY s.start
   LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT e.end   AS `date`
       , NULL    AS `name`
    FROM my_table e
   WHERE e.end   > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY
   ORDER BY e.end
   LIMIT 10
 )
 ORDER BY `date`
 LIMIT 10
```

NOTES: Since the maximum number of rows to be returned is 10, we only need to return 10 rows with the `start` date, and 10 rows with the `end` date. This will avoid creating an enormous resultset that MySQL will have to sort ("Using filesort") to get them in the right order.

We can also avoid an outer select, using an "implicit" UNION ALL operation. (This is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard, not requiring an outer query.)

We include the value of the `name` column along with the `start` dates, and we include a static dummy value for the `name` column with the `end` dates. We do this so to satisfy the requirements of the `UNION ALL` operation (i.e. number of columns and datatypes of the columns has to match.) We could just as easily supply an empty string, or any other literal value, in place of the NULL.

MySQL can satisfy the query very efficiently if a suitable indexes are available, e.g.

```
... ON my_table (`start`,`name`)
... ON my_table (`end`)
```

We're assuming that `start` and `end` are datatype `DATE`. If those are stored as `VARCHAR`, then we want to modify the expression on the right side of the inequality comparisons in the queries, so that they return compatible and comparable datatypes and values.

Comment: @Xinel: In my haste to post an answer to your question, I missed the `ORDER BY` clauses in the inner queries; the sample query in my answer is corrected to add those.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the name on the "start" times, then do:

```
select start as thedate, name
from my_table
union all
select end, NULL
from mytable
order by thedate;
```